# LSTM: How Do I Predict A Single Label Multiple Steps Ahead?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, lstm, tensorflow

I'm building an LSTM neural network using the Tensorflow tutorial below.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#single-shot_models

It shows you how to build single-step models as well as multi-step models.
However, I want to predict a single value multiple steps ahead, rather than a sequence of values.
For example, given (t-2), (t-1), (t), I want to predict (t+3) only. I do not want (t+1) or (t+2).
How do I go about this? My code is exactly the same as the one in the tutorial.

Comment: remove return_sequences=True (False by default), lstm will return only last h_t

Answer (score 1):

You can set your target variable as $y_{t+3}$ directly while training your model (whatever it is, LSTM, or another method).

Comment: How do I do that? Do you mean I do a single step model that predicts t+3? But wouldn't the LSTM still be predicting t+1? The only difference is that it's making its prediction at t+1 as close as possible to the actual value at t+3, instead of t+1. Or does this distinction not matter?